# flutter project doesnt compile

Tags: flutter, gradle

How to remove unwanted project from my project list?
Something goes wrong, after my yesterday Android Studio Update. Now I have to modules or smthing I dont know how to name it.
Before Studio update I had only one project in my project tree, but now I have this:
 [image: two projects]

My real project is on Flutter, named petsmobile.. etc.
And after update there is another one: android.

 And in Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Build Tools - Gradle
I have two projects instead of one:
[image: settings]

I tried to remove unwanted project, but didnt found where

**UPD:** For those, who has the same problem. I created new flutter project and copy all neccessary files from this broken project to new one, had been just created.

Comment: Have you tried just deleting the `android` directory?

Comment: not yet. Is it safe for my project?

Comment: It should be safe. You can back it up to somewhere first and then just copy it back if something goes wrong.

Comment: Nope. This is didnt help. Still the same as it was

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly the issue is? Do you get an error when you try to compile the project?

Comment: @flexagoon. Yes. I cant compile my project. At first time studio said, that I have wrong gradle plugin version, then, it said that I have wrong JAVA version (was 1.8 I select 11) But also the problem is that two projects are compiling at the same time: unwanted android project (there are some libraries for flutter. I dont know why they are here), wich I want to remove and my normal project.